# Перенос из локального в глобальный репозиторий

Tags: git, github

У меня на машине есть локальный репозиторий с ~ 500 комитами. Мне нужно перенести его в глобальный репозиторий, например на Github, но так что бы на там все эти комиты тоже сохранились (не только самый последний). Думал написать скрипт который просто 500  раз запушит, но думаю что наверняка есть какой - то способ попроще.

P.S. Все важные комиты в 1-ой ветке

Comment: `git push` и так запушит все коммиты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выполнение команды `push` программы *git* начинается с согласования того, на какой именно коммит ссылается обновляемый указатель («ветка») у вас и на сервере.

1. если это один и тот же коммит, выполнение команды завершается с выводом сообщения: «Everything up-to-date»
2. если «серверный» коммит отсутствует в вашем локальном хранилище (либо не является «предком» вашего локального коммита), выполнение команды завершается ошибкой «failed to push some refs…»
3. если «серверный» коммит есть в вашем локальном хранилище, и он является «предком» вашего локального коммита, то на сервер будут отправлены **в том числе и** все отсутствующие (на сервере) промежуточные коммиты. частный случай этой ситуации — это когда на сервере находится пустое хранилище. тогда будут отправлены все коммиты, связывающие ваш локальный коммит с коммитом начальным (включительно).

   таким образом, независимо от того, на сколько коммитов «длиннее» ваша локальная история коммитов, все недостающие коммиты будут отправлены на сервер **одной** командой `push`.

p.s. для простоты изложения я опустил упоминание о том, что вместе с самими объектами типа commit будут отправлены и все упомянутые в них объекты всех остальных типов (а также и все другие объекты, упомянутые в этих объектах, рекурсивно).